# How to make a Push suscription in GCP Pub/Sub with go?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, grpc, publish-subscribe, google-cloud-pubsub, grpc-go

Context:

There are one service in go that uses grcp. In that service there are a method one to one:

```
rpc CreateOrder (Order) returns (OrderId)
```

I want to create a push suscription in Google Cloud Pub/sub that invoque this method. I have read the way to make a pull suscription, but i have not found push suscription for gRPC.

Is it possible to create a push suscription via gRPC?

Comment: I believe that the [Pub/Sub Go API](https://pkg.go.dev/cloud.google.com/go/pubsub#pkg-overview) uses gRPC. Here is the [code sample](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/samples/pubsub-create-push-subscription#code-sample) to create a push subscription. Was that what you were looking for?

Comment: Yes, it's what I'm looking for. Just that the suscriptions in the dos are pull suscriptions. I need to set a push suscription instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloud Pub/Sub is a gRPC-enabled API. It has both REST and RPC interfaces. And [Pub/Sub Go](https://pkg.go.dev/cloud.google.com/go/pubsub#pkg-overview) uses gRPC.

To create a push subscription, you need to set the [PushConfig](https://pkg.go.dev/cloud.google.com/go/pubsub#PushConfig) parameter inside [SubscriptionConfig](https://pkg.go.dev/cloud.google.com/go/pubsub#SubscriptionConfig) in the [CreateSubscription](https://pkg.go.dev/cloud.google.com/go/pubsub#Client.CreateSubscription) function, which is already set in the [Go code sample](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/samples/pubsub-create-push-subscription#code-sample) from the GCP documentation:

```golang
sub, err := client.CreateSubscription(ctx, subID, pubsub.SubscriptionConfig{
                Topic:       topic,
                AckDeadline: 10 * time.Second,
                PushConfig:  pubsub.PushConfig{Endpoint: endpoint},
})
```

And to update a subscription, you need to set the [PushConfig](https://pkg.go.dev/cloud.google.com/go/pubsub#PushConfig) parameter inside [SubscriptionConfigToUpdate](https://pkg.go.dev/cloud.google.com/go/pubsub#SubscriptionConfigToUpdate) in the [update function](https://pkg.go.dev/cloud.google.com/go/pubsub#Subscription.Update):

```golang
sub := client.Subscription("subName")
    subConfig, err := sub.Update(ctx, pubsub.SubscriptionConfigToUpdate{
        PushConfig: &pubsub.PushConfig{Endpoint: "https://example.com/push"},
    })
```

Comment: Hi Ksign
But i don't need create a new subscription because i have one created. 

Its just set that subscription to push method

Comment: Thanks I will try it. I have another question, thus code must be set every time that the app run?

Comment: Once you have updated a subscription, you don't need to set the `PushConfig ` in the code every time your app run. Did you have the chance to try my answer? Consider accepting the answer if it worked or let me know if it didn't and you need more help.